# Grouping data to move up and down in a Table depending on Month day

Tags: t-sql

I am using TSQL.  I have a set of data in a table. I have a stored procedure that runs every day that populates this table. The thing is I need the order of the data to change each day of the month. This data needs to dynamically split up into 7 groups.

For example:

I have 300 pieces of data, I run the query on the first day and I have items 1-300. The second day I would run it and I would have at the top of my list 43-300 and at the bottom 1-42 (in that order). The third day I would have 86-300 on top and then 1-85 on the bottom (in that order). The fourth day and so on throughout the month would be continuing this.

I already have the initial sort, which has to remain in tack. I need a secondary sort (grouping) that would allow this movement.

I am not sure how to do this. Could anyone give me any ideas on how to do such a thing. I know how to do this if it was based on the week, but month is a bit more confusing.

Comment: How are the "cutting" numbers defined? (43, 86, etc)

Comment: the rows are being cut up into 7 groups. So I just took 300 and divided by 7 to get ~43. So 1-42 is 43 rows and 1-85 is 86 rows and so on of the theoretical data. I think I have to use NTile. But the performance doesn't seem very good.

Comment: NTile is the right choice for sorting data into an arbitrary number of 'containers' based on some evaluation

Comment: I ended up doing something a bit different then NTIle. NTILE made the execution plan look way too complicated and was a bit more labor intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that the query is:

```
SELECT 
    -- long list
FROM 
    -- complex joins
WHERE
    -- multiple conditions
ORDER BY 
    a, b ;
```

and that the cutting numbers (0, 42, 85) can be found by some functions `fun(@X)` where `@X` is a number from 1 to 7. Then we can use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT 
    -- long list
FROM 
    -- complex joins
WHERE
    -- multiple conditions
ORDER BY
    -- the "cutoff"  
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a,b) > fun(@X)
        THEN 0 ELSE 1 
    END,
    a, b ;
```

If the cutoff is as simple as diving the rows into 7 equal (or almost) parts, then we can use `((@X-1) * COUNT(*) OVER ()) / 7` as `fun(X)`, where `@X` is between 1 and 7.

If the total count of the returned rows is 300, the expression will give 0, 42, 85, 128, 171, 214 and 257.

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing.

Comment: Yes, the idea is the same but the execution more complicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing the following Idea:

```
DECLARE
@Page           INT,
@PageSize           INT,
@NumberofPartions   INT
SET @NumberofPartions = 7
SELECT @pagesize= CEILING(CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/7) FROM Table1
SELECT @page = DAY(GETDATE()) 

SELECT @page =
CASE
    WHEN @page IN (1,8,15,22,29) THEN 1
    WHEN @page IN (2,9,16,23,30) THEN 2
    WHEN @page IN (3,10,17,24,31) THEN 3
    WHEN @page IN (4,11,18,25) THEN 4
    WHEN @page IN (5,12,19,26) THEN 5
    WHEN @page IN (6,13,20,27) THEN 6
    ELSE 7
    END;
WITH 
numbered_Table1 AS
    (
    SELECT 
        t1.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.IndexID) [rownumber] 
    FROM 
        Table1 t1
    )
SELECT * 
FROM numbered_Table1 cHOA

ORDER BY
CASE WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page -1) * @pagesize AND  @page     * @pagesize THEN 1
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN  @page     * @pagesize AND (@page +1) * @pagesize THEN 2
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page +1) * @pagesize AND (@page +2) * @pagesize THEN 3
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page +2) * @pagesize AND (@page +3) * @pagesize THEN 4
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page +3) * @pagesize AND (@page +4) * @pagesize THEN 5
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page +4) * @pagesize AND (@page +5) * @pagesize THEN 6
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page +5) * @pagesize AND (@page +6) * @pagesize THEN 7
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page +7) * @pagesize AND (@page +7) * @pagesize THEN 8
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page -7) * @pagesize AND (@page -6) * @pagesize THEN 9
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page -6) * @pagesize AND (@page -5) * @pagesize THEN 10
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page -5) * @pagesize AND (@page -4) * @pagesize THEN 11
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page -4) * @pagesize AND (@page -3) * @pagesize THEN 12
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page -3) * @pagesize AND (@page -2) * @pagesize THEN 13
     WHEN cHOA.rownumber BETWEEN (@page -2) * @pagesize AND (@page -1) * @pagesize THEN 14
     END,
cHOA.IndexID
```

Was there a better way?